Find outer edge of polygon in R
I have a dataframe of longitude and latitude points which when plotted look like:

I want to define a seperate dataframe which contains all of the outer left edge. I have highlighted a few of the points here:
.
I have tried using the st_convex_hull() function as well as getBorders() which is part of the cartography package, but this gives me the whole outer edge, not just this left edge I want.

I tried a solution, but I need to know if you are OK to do some manual selection before I post it. Otherwise, you need to be more specific about what you consider "the left edge" (between southermost and northemost?)

This solution uses the northermost and southermost points to split the border with lwgeom. The desired "edge" need to be selectionned manually (two lines among three). I used meuse as example. The border is obtained with st_concave_hull(ratio=0.1) and the points are tested on it. Adjustement might be needed depending of the concavity.
library(tidyverse)
library(sf)
#> Linking to GEOS 3.11.2, GDAL 3.7.2, PROJ 9.3.0; sf_use_s2() is TRUE
library(lwgeom) # for lwgeom::st_split
#> Warning: le package 'lwgeom' a été compilé avec la version R 4.3.3
#> Linking to liblwgeom 3.0.0beta1 r16016, GEOS 3.11.2, PROJ 9.3.1
#> Warning in fun(libname, pkgname): PROJ versions differ: lwgeom has 9.3.1 sf has
#> 9.3.0
#> 
#> Attachement du package : 'lwgeom'
#> L'objet suivant est masqué depuis 'package:sf':
#> 
#>     st_perimeter
library(sp) # for meuse

data(meuse) 
df_sf = meuse %>% st_as_sf(coords= c("x","y"),remove= FALSE) %>% 
  mutate(ID= 1:n())

ggplot(data=df_sf)+geom_sf()



# Boundary
st_simplify(df_sf %>% summarise()  %>% st_concave_hull(ratio=0.1) %>% st_cast(to ="LINESTRING")) %>% 
  st_as_sfc() %>% ggplot(data=.)+geom_sf()



# Getting the points
border_point =   df_sf %>% summarise()  %>% st_concave_hull(ratio=0.1) %>% st_cast(to ="POINT") %>% 
  st_join(df_sf, .predicate = st_equals) 

# Choosing start/end point. 
MinMax =    bind_rows(border_point %>% slice_max(y), 
                      border_point %>% slice_min(y))

# Splitting along those points
boundary_split = 
lwgeom::st_split(df_sf %>% summarise()  %>% st_concave_hull(ratio=0.1) %>% st_cast(to ="LINESTRING"),
                 MinMax ) %>% 
  st_collection_extract(., "LINESTRING") %>% 
  mutate(id_line = 1:n())

# Three lines are generated, since the start/end of the linestring acts as a splitting point as well
# Plotting to identify the releveants id_line (left shore), 
boundary_split %>% 
  ggplot(data=.)+geom_sf( aes(col = id_line %>% as.factor()))



# manually selecting 
left_boundary = boundary_split %>% filter( id_line %in% c(1,2)) 

left_points =  st_join(df_sf,left_boundary  ) %>%  
  # Removing unjoinned point (NA), there is certainly a better way
  filter( id_line %in% c(1,2)) 

# Ploting elements

ggplot()+
  geom_sf(data=df_sf %>% summarise()  %>% st_concave_hull(ratio=0.1),fill=NA)+
  geom_sf(data=df_sf,col ="grey")+
  geom_sf(data =MinMax, col ="green", size =5)+
  geom_sf(data = boundary_split,aes(col = id_line %>% as.factor()) )+
  geom_sf(data = left_points, col ="red")


Created on 2024-04-16 with reprex v2.1.0

an elegant solution. Many many thanks
